# vs code did not recognize lombok

Tags: java, spring, gradle, visual-studio-code, lombok

I have an issue with my editor vscode. Recently we decided to use Lombok, but the problem that vscode did not recognize getters and setters generated by Lombok I did install the Lombok extension, but what I don't understand when I run the app it works perfectly.

Comment: How's your error like? Please describe it clearly and share the smallest needed code snippets for others to reproduce your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assumed you're using the extension [Lombok Annotations Support for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GabrielBB.vscode-lombok), from its official page:

> Lombok added as a dependency in your Java Project (Make sure you're
> using the latest version to avoid issues!) [Add with Maven](https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven) or [Add with
> Gradle](https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle)

If you're coding in Maven project, add the lombok dependency in pom.xml:

[image]

If you're coding in no build tools project, download [lombok.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.4/lombok-1.18.4.jar) then add it to referenced libraries:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because the compiler and the editor handle Lombok in different ways.
The compiler takes Lombok dependency definition(in maven, gradle, etc..) and generates code(getters, setters, constructors) in final bytecode according to usages of Lombok annotations and compile program works perfectly(check the compiled code in a text editor.).

But the editor can not know things after the compilation like generated codes([AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)) and etc...

An editor needs the plugin and a valid configuration. It seems in version 1.0.1 of VS Code Lombok extension autocomplete works perfectly but listing errors and warnings need some fixes.

Try [this fix](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Lombok-support) but don't forget [VS Code Lombok extension project](https://github.com/GabrielBB/vscode-lombok) has not been maintained for 16 months, try to use older Java versions.

Answer (score 0):

Mine solved in an unexpect way,
The item `java.jdt.ls.vmargs` in my global setting.json is overwritten in the project-level setting.json, which is located in `${project.dir}/.vscode`. It recovers when I delete project-level setting item.

I might accept some of vscode's suggestions popped up in the bottom right corner

Answer (score 0):

A note appeared on the VS Code Lombok plugin:

> Starting from 1.8.0, the Language Support for Java(TM) by RedHat
> extension has built-in support for Lombok and automatically uses the
> lombok.jar from your project classpath. The embedded lombok.jar in the
> vscode-lombok extension will be deprecated in favor of RedHat Java
> extension.

There's a settings in `settings.json` to control this feature:

```json
"java.jdt.ls.lombokSupport.enabled": true
```

Answer (score 0):

Add lombok dependency and update project settings.json with "java.jdt.ls.lombokSupport.enabled": true , this resolved the issue for Java 1.8

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).